# Subida de ficheros no funciona el Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

He estado trabajando en un servidor de almacenamiento online vía web. He desarrollado toda la funcionalidad del sistema usando *servlets* y tengo toda la gestión de archivos funcionando.

El problema es que la subida de ficheros no funciona en el navegador *Firefox*, funciona en navegadores como *Safari* o *Chrome*.

Las funciones de *Javascript* solo las he implementado para mostrar una *UI* más atractiva que la que ofrecen los formularios *HTML*.

Como decía, me gustaría ampliar la funcionalidad de subida de archivos a usuarios de *Firefox*.

Código:

```js
function validateForm() {
 var file = document.getElementById("file_to_upload");
 console.log(file);
 console.log(file.files);
 if (file.files.length == 0) {
  window.alert("Debe seleccionar un archivo para subir");
  return false;
 }
}
function upload_alternative() {
 var upload = document.getElementById("upload");
 upload.click();
}
```

```html
<form id="upload_form" method="POST" action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
    <input id="file_to_upload" type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"
        onchange="javascript:upload_alternative()" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow **En Español**, en este sitio estamos para ayudarte, siempre y cuando tus preguntas esten escritas en esta gran lengua, por favor, traducela o podria ser cerrada por la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias Ivan, lo tendré en cuenta, un saludo

Comment: @DelfinHernandezGomez debe ser algun tipo de bug de Firefox o error de motivo desconocido, elimina por completo tu `firefox` e instalalo denuevo la ultima version

Comment: @x-rw he probado desde distintos dispositivos y versiones y no se trata de eso, pero gracias!

Comment: ¿Algún error o mensaje que veas en la consola? ¿La petición llega al servidor? Añade más detalle por favor.

Comment: Resuelto, realicé una validación del código HTML y una de las etiquetas generadas de forma dinámica por el servidor no tenía cierre: "<a>... (</a>)". El resultado se reflejaba en un error en la subida porque era el elemento que se veía afectado.

Answer (score 2):

En exploradores como Chrome o Safari, cuando se omite el cierre de una etiqueta HTML se maneja el problema añadiendo una al final del elemento afectado.
En exploradores como Firefox este problema se soluciona tomando como cierre la siguiente etiqueta de la misma clase.

Por este motivo, en firefox no me permitía subir archivos ya que el elemento siguiente al afectado por la omisión del cierre de etiquetas era la opción "Subir archivos"

Gracias por las ayudas, un saludo